# How to set Tomahawk's Inputfileupload button text?

Tags: jsp, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

I'm using `myFaces` Tomahawk's components, and I can't seem to be able to add a display text for the `inputFileUpload` component button. Is there an attribute for it or do I have to assign it somewhere else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Please check the above link, I believe you can do only through CSS and JS. But not recommended